# Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null at HTMLDocument.catchIt in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So i have a simple code that tells that if there is a paragraph and user clicks on it, It should show text field and button. When you enter information in textfield and go the value in text field should be changed with textfield value. My code works fine but it gives error Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null at HTMLDocument.catchIt. Can anyone please tell how to solve it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>jobgo</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var editing  = false;

if (document.getElementById && document.createElement) {
    var butt = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    var buttext = document.createTextNode('Ready!');
    butt.appendChild(buttext);
    butt.onclick = saveEdit;
}

function catchIt(e) {
    if (editing) return;
    if (!document.getElementById || !document.createElement) return;
    if (!e) var obj = window.event.srcElement;
    else var obj = e.target;
    while (obj.nodeType != 1) {
        obj = obj.parentNode;
    }
    if (obj.tagName == 'TEXTAREA' || obj.tagName == 'A') return;
    while (obj.nodeName != 'P' && obj.nodeName != 'HTML') {
        obj = obj.parentNode;
    }
    if (obj.nodeName == 'HTML') return;
    var x = obj.innerHTML;
    var y = document.createElement('TEXTAREA');
    var z = obj.parentNode;
    z.insertBefore(y,obj);
    z.insertBefore(butt,obj);
    z.removeChild(obj);
    y.value = x;
    y.focus();
    editing = true;
}

function saveEdit() {
    var area = document.getElementsByTagName('TEXTAREA')[0];
    var y = document.createElement('P');
    var z = area.parentNode;
    y.innerHTML = area.value;
    z.insertBefore(y,area);
    z.removeChild(area);
    z.removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]);
    editing = false;
}

document.onclick = catchIt;</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have onclick event attached on the whole document and are handling everything inside that function. Now you are correctly returning when it is a TextArea or an anchor tag but are forgetting to do so for the BUTTON tag.

Since you have one more onclick handler attached for your button called saveClick() which is doing the actual job you want, your code is working as expected. You only need to return from the other onclick event handler (catchit) when you have a button. Edit like this, it will work :

```
    if (obj.tagName == 'TEXTAREA' || obj.tagName == 'A' || obj.tagName == 'BUTTON') return;
```

Comment: Yes you are right. Wish i could upvote you!!